# JMS API encoding issue when IBM MQ message is TEXT+BINARY

Tags: spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq, binary-data

I am consuming message from IBM MQ queue. Messages are of format MQSTR. But message data is TEXT+Binary. This Binary data is nothing but a JPG image
When these messages are consumed by my JMS consumer, I can see some encoding issue for Binary data, due to which transformed image is distorted from original.

I have tried every possible aspect (different IBM specification). But was not able to make through.

If someone already faced such issue please suggest possible solution for it.

Comment: 'Some encoding issue' such as what?

Comment: @user207421 updated description.

Comment: OK, now 'consumed by my JMS consumer' such as what?

Comment: Do you require the text parts of your message to be data-converted and the binary parts of your message to be left alone? Is that your requirement?

Answer (score 3):

If the message has an MQSTR MQMD.Format, then it must be a text string. MQ will convert text strings between codepages when required (eg ASCII to Unicode). If the message is not meant to be a string - which it sounds like from your limited description - then whoever creates the message needs to set the format suitably, and the receiving app must be prepared to parse and convert the message body components.